# Finding the most common time in few processes

Tags: java, split

I have one long string that says the begin and end time of processes.
I need to find the most common time here(the minute that has the most processes). 
The String looks like this: "first 15:15 12:10 second 12:50 17:10 third 20:23 22:20 ... " and more processes.
How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious solution? What was the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have to admit, even the obvious solution, when written down in Java, looks pretty complicated, mostly due to:

- the lack of pairs
- lack of `findAllIn`-regex method
- lack of `scanLeft` on `Stream`

however, here is it:

```
String data = "first 15:15 17:10 second 12:50 17:10 third 20:23 22:20 fourth 14:30 16:49";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d{2}:\\d{2} ?){2}");
LinkedList<String> matches = new LinkedList<>();
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(data);
while (matcher.find()) {
  matches.add(matcher.group(0));
}
final int[] acc_max = new int[2];

matches
  .stream()  
  .flatMap(s -> {
    String[] pieces = s.trim().split(" ");
    return Stream.of(pieces[0] + " +", pieces[1] + " -");
  })
  .sorted()
  .map(s -> s.charAt(s.length() - 1))
  .forEachOrdered(c -> {
    if (c == '+') {
      acc_max[0]++;
    } else {
      acc_max[0]--;
    }
    if (acc_max[0] > acc_max[1]) {
      acc_max[1] = acc_max[0];
    }
  });
System.out.println("Maximum number of simultaneous processes: " + acc_max[1]);
```

Brief explanation:

- regex: boring, you should have done that before even posting the question
- every pair of times is flatMapped to `start +`, `end -`, with `+` and `-` appended
- then everything is sorted
- then the times are dropped, so that only `+` and `-` remain
- integrate with `forEachOrdered`, keep current number of processes in `acc` and maximum number of processes seen so far in `max`.
- output `max` in the end.

Prints:

```
Maximum number of simultaneous processes: 3
```

Essentially the same algorithm would also give you the minute at which the maximum number of simultaneous processes is reached, but for that, you should probably model the time intervals as proper classes, instead of gluing times and `+-`-chars into strings.